# Hidden sense of Python `isinstance` function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, dynamic-typing

Reading `PyCharm` type hints for Python `isinstance` function, I noticed a very strange desing.

```py
def isinstance(__obj: object,
               __class_or_tuple: Union[type, tuple[Union[type, tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]) -> bool:

    """
    Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
    A tuple, as in isinstance(x, (A, B, ...)), may be given as the target to check against. This 
    is equivalent to isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... etc.
    """
```

I reasoned that the intent of a strange construct like `tuple[Union[type, tuple[Any, ...]], ...]` was to try to annotate a possible type recursively, which cannot be done in `Python` other than using `typing.Protocol` (which, of course, would lead to a loss of clarity). And I turned out to be right, which is confirmed by the code below.

```py
isinstance(3, (int, float, list, tuple))
>>> True
isinstance(3, (float, (int, (list,)), tuple))
>>> True
isinstance('3', (int, float, list, tuple))
>>> False
isinstance('3', (float, (int, (list,)), tuple))
>>> False
```

To be honest, this shocked me a little, because, in my opinion, it illustrates a very bad architectural solution. Moreover, in my practice I have come across situations when it would be more logical to use a `set` consisting of types, but other iterables cannot be used for this function. Only tuples (of any nesting level, as it turns out) are allowed.

```py
isinstance(3, {int, float, list, tuple})
>>> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Do you know what motives led to the decision to prohibit the use of other iterables, but allow tuples of any nesting level?

Comment: As the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) say: *"If `classinfo` is a tuple of type objects (__or recursively, other such tuples__), …"* — It's designed this way. Why it wasn't designed otherwise is often a hardly answerable question.

Comment: Guess: hardcoding a list of possible classes to check against makes total sense. Perhaps even doing so recursively, as you may have existing collections of classes, e.g. `isinstance(foo, (int, other_tuple_of_classes))`. Using a tuple for *heterogeneous* collections is a natural fit. Insisting on a tuple discourages runtime creation of *lists* of class objects, as that may be seen as a code smell. It may also be a simple optimisation thing to insist on immutable tuples.